# How to create a sub menu from an ImageMap

Tags: javascript, expression, imagemap, submenu

I have a Nav bar that I created and it is 1 image with multiple image maps... is it possible to make sub menus from the image maps in the image/Nav Bar?

Comment: If it's for a nav bar with submenus, don't use image maps.

Comment: what do you suggest I use then?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an image map, you should use a hidden unordered list for the sub menu (and show it with javascript when appropriate)

something like:

```
<a href="#" id="menuitem1">Menu Item</a>
<ul class="submenu" style="display: none;">
  <li><a href="/path">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="/path">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/path">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("#menuitem1").click(function() {
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

Comment: can you give me a little more guidance on this?

Comment: do you have any images of what you want it to look like? that would help me out a lot

Comment: well I got it to work but none of the methods above.... not sure how but it works. thanks for the help everyone though.

Answer (score 0):

try having a look at jQuery you might be able to attach a click event to an areas id which activates a hidden div with the sub menu items. www.jquery.com